# Radiotray --resume not working

Tags: gstreamer, internet-radio

When executing

```
radiotray --resume
```

It will give the output below, which basically says that --resume is loaded as being an url and not as argument.

```
Trying to load URL: --resume
Loading configuration...
/home/roel/.local/share/radiotray/bookmarks.xml
/home/roel/.local/share/radiotray/config.xml
/usr/share/radiotray/config.xml
PLS playlist decoder
M3U playlist decoder
ASX-familiy playlist decoder
XSPF playlist decoder
ASF playlist decoder
RAM playlist decoder
Using url timeout = 100
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radiotray/lib/utils.py:40: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_radio_button_set_group: assertion '!g_slist_find (group, radio_button)' failed
  ui.add_from_file(join(common.DEFAULT_CFG_PATH, name))
user chose app indicator
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/radiotray", line 15, in <module>
    radiotray.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radiotray/radiotray.py", line 35, in main
    RadioTray(argv[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radiotray/RadioTray.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.systray.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radiotray/SysTray.py", line 447, in run
    gtk.main()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Update

If found that everytime I start Radiotray from the commandline the 'first start' dialog is popped. Maybe this is an hint to what is wrong?

Comment: Where did you get "--resume" as an option - I dont see it in "radiotray --help-all" ?

Comment: @fossfreedom http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/radiotray/ticket/24 and http://www.linuxlearningzone.com/radiotray-0-6-3-released-with-ubuntu-appindicator-support-sleep-timer/ can't find the release notes but saw that it was noted their too. The --help-all indeed didn't show show the argument.

Comment: Going by the answer this is a bug in the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 11.10 the Radiotray version is 0.6.4. The latest release is 0.7 so i decided to download latest .deb from sourceforge and installed the latest version on my PC. This solved the issue.